# Formula to make the outputs of two separate Filter functions display consecutively

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

So I have a workbook with 3 sheets.  The first contains data from A:Z.  The second also contains data from A:Z, but the data is different.  The third page is used to query the other by using Filter.

I want to be able to write a single formulate that will Filter data from sheet 1 and display the results, and then starting from the next available row, Filter data from sheet2 and display those results, without any gaps or overwriting.

If the two filters are something like this:

`=FILTER(sheet1!A:Z, sheet1!A:A="Bob")`
and
`=FILTER(sheet2!A:Z, sheet2!A:A="Bob")`

So, the only difference between the two filters is the sheet name.

I won't know in advance how many rows of output each filter will produce, so I can't just put the second Filter formula in a cell in a lower row, because I don't want there to be any blanks rows between the two sets of output.

I thought that I could use COUNT or COUNTA to work out how many rows of output there's be from the first Filter formula, but even knowing that, how could I choose in which row the second Filter would begin displaying results?

I thought of using &, but that just puts the first result from each sheet into one cell and gives no other rows or columns of results.
I tried ARRAYFORMULA, but I've never used that before and don't think it is suitable.
I tried JOIN, but it gives an error saying it can only be used for a single row or a single column.

UPDATE: Here's my new code, based on player0's advice

`={IFERROR(FILTER('2019 (H904)'!B9:AK, '2019 (H904)'!C9:C=A1, '2019 
     (H904)'!J9:J=E1), SUBSTITUTE(COLUMN(B9:AK)^0, 1, );
   IFERROR(FILTER('2018 (H517)'!B9:AK, '2018 (H517)'!C9:C=A1, '2018 
     (H517)'!J9:J=E1), SUBSTITUTE(COLUMN(B9:AK)^0, 1, )}))`

But I get a formula parse error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put them in array:

```
={FILTER(sheet1!A:Z, sheet1!A:A="Bob"); 
  FILTER(sheet2!A:Z, sheet2!A:A="Bob")}
```

the issue is if one of them outputs nothing. then you need something like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({
 IFERROR(FILTER(sheet1!A:Z, sheet1!A:A="Bob"), SUBSTITUTE(COLUMN(A:Z)^0, 1, ); 
 IFERROR(FILTER(sheet2!A:Z, sheet2!A:A="Bob"), SUBSTITUTE(COLUMN(A:Z)^0, 1, )}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0))
```

Comment: hi, what does the col1 represents in the above query?

Comment: @Ankur in QUERY when range is direct like for example A:C then query syntax uses column names so it would be "select A,B,C". if the range is constructed with formula or multiple ranges like for example: {A:B, C:C} then query syntax uses Col references so it would be "select Col1,Col2,Col3"